# Can I use non volatile external variables in Scala Enumeratee?

Tags: scala, concurrency, playframework, enumeration, volatile

I need to group output of my Enumerator in different ZipEntries, based on specific property (providerId), original chartPreparations stream is ordered by providerId, so I can just keep reference to provider, and add a new entry when provider chages

```
        Enumerator.outputStream(os => {
            val currentProvider = new AtomicReference[String]()
            // Step 1. Creating zipped output file
            val zipOs = new ZipOutputStream(os, Charset.forName("UTF8"))
            // Step 2. Processing chart preparation Enumerator
            val chartProcessingTask = (chartPreparations) run Iteratee.foreach(cp => {
                // Step 2.1. Write new entry if needed
                if(currentProvider.get() == null || cp.providerId != currentProvider.get()) {
                    if (currentProvider.get() != null) {
                        zipOs.write("</body></html>".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF8")))
                    }
                    currentProvider.set(cp.providerId)
                    zipOs.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(cp.providerName + ".html"))
                    zipOs.write(HTML_HEADER)
                }
                // Step 2.2 Write chart preparation in HTML format
                zipOs.write(toHTML(cp).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF8")))
            })
            // Step 3. On Complete close stream
            chartProcessingTask.onComplete(_ => zipOs.close())
        })
```

Since current provider reference, is changing, during the output, I made it AtomicReference, so that I could handle references from different threads.

Can currentProvider just be a var Option[String], and why?

Comment: Do you have non-threadsafe context and so that you use `AtomicReference`? Or what? Because I can't see what is the benefit of `AtomictReference`. Also if you want to use Option you will have to rewrite that to use `foldLeft` because `Option[T]` is not mutable.

Comment: By Option, I meant using var reference, not val reference. AtomicReference allows you to work correctly in multithreaded environment, and since processing of foreach does not necessarily happens in the same Thread, I wonder if AtomicReference needed, to guarantee correct work of the method.

Comment: First of all I can't see this multithreaded environment in your code. And even if there is one if you enclose something in `val` it stays as it is. Secondly here is [Option implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L1) and as you can see there is no threadsafety there.